# Why does the assuming not work as expected?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Why does this not work? I expect the output would be something like `1/s*e^-(sT)`.

```
Assuming[T > 0, 
  LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: `FullSimplify[LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s], T > 0]` and I don't know the exact reason for this.

Comment: @Syed what would be the reason that my code not work?

Comment: `Assuming[T > 0, Refine[LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]]]`

Comment: @Syed I see. I only works with some functions such as Refine or Simplify. So I probably always have to wrap the expression around these functions.

Comment: Please wait for a knowledgeable/definitive answer by a developer perhaps.

Comment: I'm neither a developer nor very knowledgeable, but I think I do have the answer. Please do let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR;

You have to put [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) inside [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) because `Assuming` does not change the properties of an expression but instead, it creates a limited scope with a modified value for `$Assumptions`

## Long Explanation

`Assuming` is not been used by `LaplaceTransform` to do `FullSimplify` and where you place the your explicit `FullSimplify` with respect `Assuming` matters.

### Background

Not all functions take `$Assumptions` into account, most will just ignore it.

From the documentation

> `Assuming[assum,expr]` evaluates `expr` with `assum` appended to
> `$Assumptions`, so that `assum` is included in the default assumptions
> used by functions such as `Refine`, `Simplify`, and `Integrate`.
> Assuming affects the default assumptions for all functions that have an
> Assumptions option.

[image]

`LaplaceTransform` does have [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) as [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) so it will give you an answer that is compatible with those `$Assumptions`

```
MemberQ[Assumptions]@Keys[Options[LaplaceTransform]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

However, `LaplaceTransform` doesn't use those `$Assumptions` to [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) the expression the way you may expect, as `FullSimplify` can take too long to run or it may go too far and do something you may not necessarily want .

The documentation for `FullSimplify` warns :

> Some of the transformations used by `FullSimplify` are only generically correct.
>
> Results of simplification of singular expressions are uncertain.

### Your case

Now, look at the order you are evaluating things, by the time `FullSimplify` evaluates the expression, your specified `$Assumptions` have been dropped.

```
Assuming[
  T > 0,  (* Modified $Assumptions affect LaplaceTransform *)
  LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]
] // FullSimplify  (* Only default $Assumptions affect FullSimplify  *)
```

[image]

By changing the evaluation order, you can make `FullSimplify` to be within the scoping environment where `$Assumptions` is modified.

```
Assuming[
  T > 0,  (* Modified $Assumptions affect both LaplaceTransform and FullSimplify *)
  LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s] // FullSimplify
]
```

[image]

Think of `Assuming` as equivalent to

```
Block[
   { $Assumptions = T>0 },
   LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]
]
```

If you leave `FullSimplify` outside `Block` then it will not see the modified `$Assumptions`.

```
Block[
   { $Assumptions = T>0 },
   LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]
] // FullSimplify
```

If you put  `FullSimplify` inside `Block` then it will see the modified `$Assumptions`.

```
Block[
   {$Assumptions =T>0},
   LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s] // FullSimplify
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detalied and interesting answer.  Why does the assumption not have any effect in this case `Block[
   {$Assumptions =T>0},
   LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]
]`?

Comment: It does, but as explained, `LaplaceTransform` will give you an answer that is consistent with the `$Assumptions` but without attempting to simplify the answer in the same way `FullSimplify` does.

Comment: But `LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s]` produces the same exact expression without using assumption. Or LaplaceTransform just assumed T > 0 by default somehow?

Comment: @internet I don't understand  your last comment.

Comment: These two codes give the exact same result: `Block[
   {$Assumptions =T>0},
   LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s] ] ` and `LaplaceTransform[UnitStep[t - T], t, s] `. So the Block with the assumption doesn't seem to be used in the first case.

Comment: I answered that already, FullSimply does more transformations.